# How to change attribute in selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

I need change `src` attribute in `img` tag with selenium in python.

Browser is `firefox`.

`HTML` code:

```
<div style="" id="image_sec">
    <img src="city.png" alt="">
</div>
```

need change to:

```
<div style="" id="image_sec">
    <img src="new_city.png" alt="">
</div>
```

`Python` code:

```
driver.execute_script('$("#image_sec img").innerHtml(<img src="new_city.png" alt="">);')
```

But this code is not work :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to implement below line

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#image_sec>img").src="new_city.png";')
```

or

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#image_sec>img").setAttribute("src", "new_city.png");')
```